# sequences containing the digits '2016'?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A sequence can be created where the 1st 3 terms are 1, 4, 5 and every term after that is the sum of all proceeding terms (e.g. 1, 4, 5, 10...) how many of such sequences beginning with 1 and containing the digits 2016 are there?

I'm not sure where to start. I found that the digits of the sequence are just double the digit before them and if you keep halving 2016 you end up with 63 but I'm not sure how that would be useful.

Comment: It is not clear which sequences you are referring to, since you described just one of them. Also, changing "digit" to "term" might help a little.

Comment: So you are asking which sequences $1, a_{2}, a_{3}, \dots$ are there where $a_{i} = 1 + a_{2} + \dots + a_{i-1}$ for $i > 2$, such that $a_{n} = 2016$ for some $n$?

Comment: The answer to this depends only on what the second term of your sequence is, because then  the whole sequence is decided.

Comment: To me it is unclear whether the first term must always be 1, or whether already the third term is always the sum of the preceding terms ...

Comment: I interpreted the question as the number of sequences that start with '1, 4, 5' (not following the rule) and every term after that is a sum of the proceeding terms (e.g. 1, 4, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80...)

Comment: But then no term is 2016 of this sequence

Comment: I thought it meant that the sequence could be like (13510204080......2016......)??

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume that you consider sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of positive integers with the property that $a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k$ for all $n>2$ (or only for $n>3$?).

Your observation that (except at the very beginning) the terms double with each step, is correct because
$$a_{n+1}= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=a_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k=a_n+a_n$$
for $n>2$.

- We have infinitely many such sequences with $a_1=2016$, as well as infinitely many with $a_2=2016$
- There are $2015$ such sequences with $a_3=2016$: We can pick $1\le a_1\le 2015$ arbitrarily, then $a_2=2016-a_1$ and voíla!
- There are $1007$ such sequences with $a_4=2016$: We then must have $a_3=1008$ and find $1007$ solutions as in the preceding point
- We can continue this by dividing out more powers of two (i.e., find $503$ such sequences with $a_5=2016$, etc.)

In total we find (ignoring the infinitely many sequences from the first bullet point)
$$\begin{align}2016-1+\frac{2016}2-1+\frac{2016}4-1+\ldots+\frac{2016}{32}-1&=2016\cdot(1+\tfrac12+\ldots+\tfrac1{32}) -6\\
&=2016\cdot(2-\tfrac1{32})-6\end{align}$$

Comment: Wait but the answer is a number from 0 to 9 (it was multiple choice)

Comment: Then maybe you should tell us what the question was, for now we have nothing but assumptions and guesses.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have another assumption as to the supposed meaning of this question. Let's say that we always have $a_1=1$, and $a_2$ is whatever we want, while $a_3$ and onwards are defined as sums of preceding terms. How many of **these** sequences would contain 2016 as a term? Well, then the answer is indeed somewhere between 0 and 9, as we can easily list them all:
$$\begin{array}{l}
1,2016\dots\\
1,2015,2016\dots\\
1,1007,1008,2016\dots\\
1,503,504,1008,2016\dots\\
1,251,252,504,1008,2016\dots\\
1,125,126,252,504,1008,2016\dots\\
1,62,63,126,252,504,1008,2016\dots\\
\end{array}$$